Blazor Radio Button with checked and aria-describedby
I'm writing a Blazor application (server side, .NET 8.0), that has radio buttons. I am using the generic <input> HTML instead of a .NET component. This is a standard "loop through all the answers and mark the one that is selected".
      @foreach (var answer in Component.Answers.Where(a => !a.NotObserved || ShowNotObserved).Select((value, i) => new { i, value }))
      {
          <div class="first first-@answer.value.NumberColumns first-mobilerow-@answer.i">
              <input type="radio" value="@answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer" checked="@(ComponentAnswer == null ? false : answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer == ComponentAnswer.QuantitativeScore)" disabled="@(IsReadOnly && !(ComponentAnswer == null ? false : answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer == ComponentAnswer.QuantitativeScore))" name="@Component.Code" id="@Component.Code-@answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer" aria-describedby="description-@Component.Code-@answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer" @onchange="e => SaveAnswer(answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer, answer.value.QualitativeAnswer, answer.value.Description)" />
              <div id="description-@Component.Code-@answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer" style="display: none;">@answer.value.Description</div>
              <label for="@Component.Code-@answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer">@answer.value.Answer(ShowQuantitativeAnswer)</label>
          </div>
      }

This seems very cargo cult programming, but when I move the checked attribute after the aria-describedby attribute, sometimes none of the radio buttons are selected (even if I add a statement confirming that the statement is true: answer.value.QuantitativeAnswer == ComponentAnswer.QuantitativeScore). This doesn't happen all the time but enough that I can repeat the issue.
Is there something that could short-circuit the checked attribute? Order of the attributes shouldn't matter, correct? Thanks!
Edited
The name attribute is fixed based on the question -- here's the code from DevTools
<div class="first first-1 first-mobilerow-0"><input type="radio" value="1" name="1a" id="1a-1" aria-describedby="description-1a-1"><!--!-->
                <div id="description-1a-1" style="display: none;">The teacher lacks sufficient knowledge of content and pedagogy to support student learning of the content.</div><!--!-->
                <label for="1a-1">Needs Improvement (1)</label></div>


It looks like the name of the radio button will keep changing depending on the selection. Blazor refresh rules are non-trivial. I suggest you use another time/selection invariant key to name the radio button. That might work.

Hi @bryanjonker, In Blazor, you should use @bind to handle the checked state of radio buttons. This helps ensure that Blazor correctly manages the state of the input elements. Have your tried it?

Thanks! I think I'm doing radio buttons wrong. However, the name attribute is fixed and unique to the question.
@Rena -- how would you do binding and represent the full range of values in the radio buttons (in this case, 1-5)?
